# Change header section width but keep it inline with content width?

Tags: html, css

Howto change header section into a smaller width but in the sametime have it inline with content column width.

This is a picture of what I am talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSN7D.jpg

You see the header section is smaller then the content column. But they are still inline.

Comment: You can use a `<span>` element with a class to change the word or phrase inside a text block. If you want more specific help please post some code with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Set width:100% and position:absolute to your header.

Comment: This works. I also find out that padding-right: and then set what you need of px. Is this a good way to do it? @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) { padding:0 }

Comment: But, it will not be suitable for all browsers with different widths. Better to use width as 100%.

Comment: Sorry, I can note vote yet. Need 15 in rep. When I use width:100% and position:absolute to your header. It will not be responsive? When I am looking in responsive.

Comment: Responsive in the sense?

Comment: Yes, it will not break. So the text makes needed to be scrolled sideways.

Comment: Can you please make it in jsfiddle so that I can take a look at it to provide you an appropriate solution for you.

Comment: I can give you my direct link. You will find it in the source code. http://sindreolsson.tumblr.com